# How to write a SQL statement for listing all Makes that have more than three Types

Tags: sql

How to write a SQL statement for listing all `Makes` that have more than three `Types`

below is the table of data

```
Make           Model                            Type
Chrysler       Crossfire 2dr                    Sports
Ford           Crown Victoria 4dr               Sedan
Ford           Crown Victoria LX 4dr            Sedan
Ford           Crown Victoria LX Sport 4dr      Sedan
Honda          CR-V LX                          SUV
Cadillac       CTS VVT 4dr                      Sedan
Dodge          Dakota Club Cab                  Truck
Dodge          Dakota Regular Cab               Truck
Cadillac       Deville 4dr                      Sedan
Cadillac       Deville DTS 4dr                  Sedan
Mitsubishi     Diamante LS 4dr                  Sedan
Land Rover     Discovery SE                     SUV
Dodge          Durango SLT                      SUV
Mercedes-Benz  E320                             Wagon
Mercedes-Benz  E320 4dr                         Sedan
Mercedes-Benz  E500                             Wagon
```

Comment: Select Makes from cars Where Count(types) > 3

Comment: Please put in your table structure and the code you tried for better help.

Comment: Do you mean more than three types or ore than three different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group your rows by make <strike>& type</strike> and then use `having` in your sql. something like this:

```
SELECT make FROM cars
GROUP BY make
HAVING COUNT(type) > 3
```

[`HAVING`](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/having) is like `WHERE` when grouping

EDIT: removed `type` column from GROUP BY

Comment: Why grouping by type?? Columns in group by must be in select clause

Comment: @Hadi yes you're correct, its too early in the morning here :\

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query

```
SELECT make FROM cars
GROUP BY make
HAVING COUNT(type) > 3
```

*Side Note: In general, All column names in SELECT list must appear in GROUP BY clause unless name is used only in an aggregate function*

The SQL GROUP BY clause is used in collaboration with the SELECT statement to arrange identical data into groups. The GROUP BY clause follows the WHERE clause in a SELECT statement and precedes the ORDER BY clause.

Learn more about `Group BY` in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean more than three different types. So use `COUNT DISTINCT` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT make
FROM cars
GROUP BY make
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) > 3
```